# Attempting to save webscraping to csv file with no luck

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

The result is printed correctly, but the csv file stops at the first iteration and repeats itself.

Here is the code :

```
**with open('stocknews.csv','w') as new_file:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=' ')
    csv_reader=csv.reader('stocknews.csv')
    i=0
    lenght=len(soup.find_all('div',{'class':'eachStory'}))**
    **for i in range(lenght):
        print(i+1,")")
        headlines+=[soup.find_all('div',{'class':'eachStory'})[.   i].find_all('a')[-1].text]
        descriptions+=[soup.find_all('div',{'class':'eachStory'}).  [i].find_all('p')[0].text]
        print(headlines[i])
        print(descriptions[i])** 
        **i+=1
        print(i)
        for i in csv_reader :
            csv_writer.writerow(['headlines','descriptions'])
            csv_writer.writerow([headlines, descriptions])**
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the last few lines. i.e. csv_writer.writerow.. I've tried many things but never managed to save to csv correctly.

Comment: So.. where is the webscraping in your question?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire `soup.find_all` is the webscraping (with beautiful soup)

Comment: are you trying to read and write to the same file? i think opening the file in 'w' mode has some repercussions if you were trying to read and write while iteratively moving the pointer. Just making sure you actually intended to read and write to the same file or if it's a mistake.

Comment: @topsail, `soup.find_all` is *parsing*, not *webscraping*. There is a difference. OP's question is not about webscraping, is about working with csv. There is no mention of any url being scraped.

Comment: Just google "webscraping with beautiful soup" - no need to be so particular about definitions. Obviously, the OP wants to save the results to csv, but you are the one who asked where the webscraping is and that's the answer (even if you don't like the terminology).

Comment: You're mixing up scraping, with parsing. You cannot scrape anything with beautifulsoup, you do that with requests, selenium, etc, and then you eventually **extract** the results with bs4(BeautifulSoup) from the scraped data. You may want to check the documentation for bs4, prior to suggesting others to google stuff.

Comment: I know what beautifulsoup is. My point is that loosely speaking you can call it webscraping when you use it with web pages (and not only me but lots of people speak that way - hence the google search which I have suggested). Obviously if you don't have a web page to parse you are neither parsing nor web scraping - lets not fight about terminology its not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer (There are a lot of things I don't quite understand about your code and I can't test it without any data to work with).

However,

```
for i in csv_reader :
    csv_writer.writerow(['headlines','descriptions'])
    csv_writer.writerow([headlines, descriptions])**
```

This is a loop over a csv_reader but what are you actually looping over? Normally you don't loop over csv_reader (I have never seen this actual construction before). Normally you loop over some collection - such as the lines in a text file which you have read.  As far as I can tell, you are looping the csv_reader *itself*. There is only one csv_reader. hence, only one loop.

This would be more typical:

```
lines = csv_reader.readlines()
for line in lines:
    pass #do something
```

I have no idea why you have double asterisks sprinkled around your code. I would suggest you to break this down and step through each line carefully - is it doing what you think it is doing? Is each intermediate step correct? There isn't a lot of code here, but 1) is the reading of the file working? 2) are the headlines and descriptions being read as you expect? 3) Once you have the headlines and descriptions, are they being written out correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I ended up being able to save with **topics_dict = {"headlines":[], "descriptions":[]}topics_dict["headlines"].append(headlines)
    topics_dict["descriptions"].append(descriptions)
    topics_data = pd.DataFrame(topics_dict)
    
topics_data.to_csv('indianews.csv', index=False) 
topics_data